# How can I fix Error -101 in the Market?

Tags: google-play-store

I added a second Google account to my Dell Streak 5 running 2.2 and when I attempt to download an app (either paid or free) through the Market I get this error:

> <App Name> could not be downloaded due to an error. (-101)

Downloading apps through the primary account on the device works just fine.  I've tried downloading over both data and Wi-Fi as well as removing and re-adding the secondary account and clearing the Market data, with no luck.  I'm using the 3.4.4 Market though this also occurs with the 3.1.3 Market.  Also of note is that the device doesn't show up in the web Market — it only lists my Vibrant.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you'd get a chuckle from this post: [Unable to install or update apps via market](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20887155&postcount=6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried removing and adding both account? Or adding secondary account as primary account. Making secondary account primary may not be what you want but its worth a try.

Comment: A wipe and re-adding the accounts in the same way worked.  Guess I'll never know what happened.  Accepting since yours was first and would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried erasing all user data on your device, then re-adding both accounts? To do this, go to Settings - Security - Wipe Data.

Comment: A wipe and re-adding the accounts in the same way worked.  Guess I'll never know what happened.  Bountying since your answer is more direct.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue on my Asus Transformer Prime tablet. Fixed by updating the timezone to the proper one, Settings -> Date & time.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know whether the timezone was correct for me but I'll test this out.